# Need help to install software on a Mac Mini I have one Macbook

Tags: display, mac-mini

Recently I purchased a Mac Mini base model and need to access several CD to install software (for a Dell S2230MX monitor and the wireless router)

As is known by some, the Mac Mini does not come with CD / DVD. I searched the site search how to install software on the Mac Mini but came up blank. As I understand it, but with a Macbook can install programs on the Mac Mini from it's DVD drive.

I do not want to buy a super drive from Apple to fix this. How do I set things up?

Comment: É melhor você perguntar em inglês.

Comment: If I am reading the translation correctly, the monitor needs drivers? Have you tried plugging in the display already? Unless the display has very special features, it should 'just work'.

Comment: No. The monitor does not need drives. I need to know how to install softwares on the MacMini using the Macbook. Such as the installation CD for Dell monitor and a Linksys  Wireless router. Sorry for the translation. Thank you very much. I will follow the information given by SSteve and read the article. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You need to share the optical drive from the MacBook. Go to System Preferences -> Sharing -> and turn on "DVD or CD sharing". There's more information in [this Apple support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5287).

Comment: Do I need any kind of cable?

Comment: No, not for sharing. Just both devices need to be on the same network.

Comment: You can always connect an ethernet cable or firewire cable between the two macs and open network preferences on each. As long as the network connection is green or yellow - the two devices will talk to each other well enough to run the Remote Disk software.

Answer (score 1):

On your MacBook open the Terminal and type this

```
defaults write com.apple.NetworkBrowser EnableODiskBrowsing -bool true
defaults write com.apple.NetworkBrowser ODSSupported -bool true
```

Then you will be able to turn on CD/DVD Sharing via the Sharing System Preferences panel.

On your Mac Mini you should then be able to install from the DVD that's in the MacBook's drive.